# Confused about Rust imports

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to use the [azure-devops-rust-api](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-rust-api/tree/main/azure_devops_rust_api) package in my code with `use azure_devops_rust_api::git::ClientBuilder;`, for example. This made sense to me, reading [the docs](https://docs.rs/azure_devops_rust_api/latest/azure_devops_rust_api/git/struct.ClientBuilder.html). But the compiler keep raising:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `azure_devops_rust_api::git`
 --> src/main.rs:7:28
  |
7 | use azure_devops_rust_api::git::ClientBuilder;
  |                            ^^^ could not find `git` in `azure_devops_rust_api
```

My Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
azure_devops_rust_api = "0.7.5"
```

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something fundamental but I don't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [behind a feature](https://docs.rs/azure_devops_rust_api/0.7.5/src/azure_devops_rust_api/lib.rs.html#47-48):

> ```rust
> #[cfg(feature = "git")]
> pub mod git;
> ```

Just enable it with this line in your `Cargo.toml`

```ini
[dependencies]
azure_devops_rust_api = { version = "0.7.5", features = ["git"] }
```

or

```bash
cargo add azure_devops_rust_api -F git
```

Comment: Okay I understand how `features` work now. The solution was right in front of me in the definition of azure_devops_rust_api in my IDE...